# Langchain Agent to question CSV/dataframe doesn't filter and save the resulting dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, openai-api, langchain

I'm experimenting with Langchain to analyze csv documents. I'm using the  `create_pandas_dataframe_agent` to create an agent that does the analysis with OpenAI's `GPT-3.5-turbo-0613` model.

It's easy to get the agent going, I followed the examples in the Langchain Docs. However, I haven't found a way to actually filter a dataframe and save (or access) the result.

Here's an example:

```py
# Create a dummy dataframe with columns id, name, and description and fill it with 5 rows.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'name': ["Spark", "Hadoop", "Pandas", "Java", "Pyspark"],
    'description': ["30 days course with a fee of 20000 and a discount of 1000",
                    "40 days course with a fee of 25000 and a discount of 2500",
                    "35 days course with a fee of 30000 and a discount of 1500",
                    "60 days course with a fee of 22000 and a discount of 1200",
                    "50 days course with a fee of 26000 and a discount of 3000"]
}

df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I create an agent to analyse the dataframe, for example ask how many rows there are:

```py
from langchain.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
import os
from getpass import getpass

# Get OpenAI API key
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = getpass('Enter your OpenAI API key: ')

agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
    ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"),
    df_tmp,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS
)

agent.run("how many rows are there?")
```

This outputs what we would expect:

```
> Entering new  chain...

Invoking: `python_repl_ast` with `df.shape[0]`


5There are 5 rows in the dataframe.

> Finished chain.
'There are 5 rows in the dataframe.'
```

But what I want is that the agent changes the df_tmp by filtering it, and then return a copy of the changed dataframe (or save it to a file).

```py
...
agent.run("save df to csv")
```

Resulting in:

````
> Entering new  chain...
To save the dataframe `df` to a CSV file, you can use the `to_csv()` method in pandas. Here's an example:

df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)


This will save the dataframe to a file named "filename.csv" in the current directory. The `index=False` parameter is used to exclude the index column from the CSV file.

> Finished chain.
'To save the dataframe `df` to a CSV file, you can use the `to_csv()` method in pandas. Here\'s an example:\n\n```python\ndf.to_csv(\'filename.csv\', index=False)\n```\n\nThis will save the dataframe to a file named "filename.csv" in the current directory. The `index=False` parameter is used to exclude the index column from the CSV file.'
````

How can I access the changed dataframe variable? Or how can I save the df to a file so that I can access it using `pd.read_csv`?

For example I'd like to do this (not working code):

```
df_filtered = agent.run('filter df on name is Pandas')

print(len(df_filtered))
=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it is still about prompting; so you can say

```
response = agent.run('return the row ids for courses with fee less than 3000 as a list of integers. if there is no exact match return an empty list')
```

then your `response` variable is a string which you can parse and turn it into integers and subset your dataframe with respect to that.